# What is the etymology of the phrase "see what one had for breakfast"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-origin

This phrase is usually referred to women who (accidentally?) reveals more than intended because of such as wearing a short skirt or falling over and having their clothes flip over and thus reveal their bottoms or something. What I want to know is how this phrase came about to mean what it means. I see no connection between either falling or a wardrobe malfunction and breakfast. The closest answer to this I found is not even an answer, it is a record of when this was first mentioned, and supposedly it was mentioned in 1973, according to this website:

https://wordhistories.net/2020/03/05/see-womans-breakfast/

It does't explain how the phrase came about and why it means what it means. Does anyone know?

Comment: Words have etymologies; phrases do not. They have origins. Also, please correct your title. It is missing the word woman.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the phrase relating to a person yawning or otherwise opening their mouth very wide. The idea being that you could see so far down the throat that you could see their first meal of the day. Exactly how this has become transferred to seeing up a young woman's skirt I really don't know.

Comment: I'd guess it's related to the sense BoldBen mentions - being able to see inside someone - although it appears a less common version than the wide-open mouth. But a lot of men have a limited idea of female anatomy, so maybe they think it's all connected. A good slang dictionary may help; it's on Urban Dictionary but not very highly voted or very informative.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this expression, so I trawled through a few examples on Google Books. There are only about a dozen instances of [*could see what **she** had for breakfast*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22could+see+what+she+had+for+breakfast%22), and they all seem to be specifically calling attention to a short skirt. And just 5 of [*could see what **he** had for breakfast*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22could+see+what+he+had+for+breakfast%22) - one with tight jeans, one who vomited, one "guileless / transparent", the rest "indeterminate".

Comment: So I think the allusion is too "not very far down" (from the mouth), which thus leads on to "very high" (of a skirt "hemline"), rather than to actually being able to ***see*** (visible "private parts", up a girl's skirt). That kinda makes it an extension of @BoldBen's "wide yawning" sense (which does kinda ring a bell to me).

Comment: ...first result from my GB search above: *Before I could turn, she would come out, bend over to pick up her paper, usually **in shorts** or a skirt. **Either way**, I could see what she had for breakfast.* Clearly *that* writer was only referring to how *high* the bottom of shorts / top of skirt was, since he wouldn't literally "see" anything he shouldn't if she was wearing "short shorts".

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP's link shows "see her breakfast" rather than "see what she had for breakfast." Seems to be using "breakfast" as a slang term for parts of the body that are usually covered?

Comment: @Esther: Ah, right. I see OP's link also has *The phrase **to see a woman’s breakfast** can refer ... to (the **contours** of) a woman’s genitals as revealed for example by a very short skirt* (basically, *"Camel toe alert!* :) But the bottom line is it has so little currency that it's hardly surprising different people have different understandings of exactly what it's getting at.

Answer (score -1):

It means the person is making a rude comment. I can see what u had for breakfast means I can see all the way up u, if they get a look up your skirt. It's just a common rude thing to say.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).